Native AOT - 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
I am trying to call Native AOT library published with -
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release
from managed C# class method (Debug - Any CPU).
I am getting below error -
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
Below is my Code -
Native Lib -
`using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class NativeExports
{
    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "multiply")]
    public static IntPtr multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        IntPtr ptr;
        try
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Value");
            table.Rows.Add(a*b);
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(table);
            ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch);
            return ptr;
        }
        catch 
        {
            // TODO this function has no way to propagate errors
            table.Rows.Add(-1);
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(table);
            ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch);
            return ptr;
        }
    }
}

`
C# Caller -
`...
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class MulCsPinvoke
{
    [DllImport("mul")]
    static extern IntPtr multiply(int a, int b);

    public static void Main()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        var c = multiply(7, 6);
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(c);
        Object tw = gch.Target;
        //error at below line , unable to read tw 
        table = (DataTable)tw;
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(c);
    }
}

...`
I was expecting memory pointer back . And using target of GCHandle I am trying to cast memory back to DataTable.
Thanks in Advance !
